# if P = NP, does it mean that P = NP = NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, p-vs-np, check-my-answer

Lets **assume P = NP**, so all problems in NP are decidable in polynomial time,
Therefore I can solve all problems in NP in polynomial claiming **P = NP = NPC**.

But then, how come Σ* belongs to P = NPC because I can't reduce the even length string language (as an example of a language that is not trivial) to Σ*?

one of the steps I made must be incorrect (I sure hope so)
please help me find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Even assuming $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$, it is not true that all the languages therein are $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.

An example of a language that is in $P$ but it is not $NP$-complete (regardless of the $P$ vs $NP$ matter) is $\Sigma^*$, as you noticed. Indeed, there is no way to reduce any language $L \in \mathsf{NP} \setminus \{ \Sigma^* \}$ to $\Sigma^*$ since, given $x \not\in L$, there is no function $f$ such that $f(x) \not\in \Sigma^*$.
A similar argument shows that $\emptyset$ is not $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.

However, if $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$, then it is true that all languages in $\mathsf{NP} \setminus \{\emptyset, \Sigma^*\}$ are $\mathsf{NP}$-complete. To see this, let $A \in \mathsf{NP} \setminus \{\emptyset, \Sigma^*\}$ and pick any $L \in \mathsf{NP}$. Since there are $y,z$ such that $y \in A$ and $z \not\in A$, a valid Karp reduction from $L$ to $A$ is the following:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
y & \text{if } x \in L \\
z & \text{if } x \not\in L
\end{cases}.
$$
Notice that $f$ can be computed in polynomial time since $L \in \mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{P}$ by hypothesis (and hence it is possible to check whether $x \in L$ in polynomial time).

Comment: thank you very much! clear explanation.